# Omniture implementation: Fallback visitor ID vs first party cookies

Tags: cookies, analytics, adobe-analytics

Beginning with code version H.25.3, Omniture introduced a new cookie that will serve as a fallback method in case your third-party cookies are not accepted.

Can anyone tell me if there are any drawbacks when using this method? Why would someone use the first party cookie implementation instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following information answers my question. They come straight from Adobe [1](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/want-a-cookie/).

**Visitor accuracy matches true first party cookies:**
This solution sets a first party cookie and its rejection rate is as low as any first party cookie implementation.

**Visitor Uniqueness:**
The methodology used to generate the s_fid value does not guarantee a unique value for each visitor. Factors that impact uniqueness include the volume of s_fid values set across the site and the number of concurrent hits from visitors who arrive at the same millisecond. It’s important to note that the odds of this are very low, and you shouldn’t notice an even remotely significant difference between visitor counts using this methodology and using CNAME first-party cookies.

**Decrease in visitors after code update:**
If you update your analytics code to H.25.3 or higher, you may see an overall decrease in your visitor count because of the decrease in overall cookie rejection.

http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/want-a-cookie/

Answer (score 1):

This document has a little additional information on the fallback method:
http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/index.html#Identifying_Unique_Visitors

There actually aren't too many drawbacks using the fallback method, however if you're using SSL or defining your own visitorIDs, it will be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks Russ. I have seen this document before.

I am trying to understand what the exact drawbacks would be. On which occasions would the fallback ID, fail to provide an accurate traffic estimation. I keep getting vague answers that the fallback ID is not as "accurate" as the FPC implementation, but I was not find out why.

Answer (score 1):

A `s.VisitorID` can be used for cross-device stitching i.e. identifying a visitor across different devices since it is set by us by configuring `visitorAPI.js`.

Answer (score 0):

The main drawback is that IP addresses and other user agent string can very easily be spoofed.  While most people don't go out of their way to do this, many browser addons and other software meant to protect the privacy of people will mask or spoof this stuff, and many times it's a default settings.  So as privacy concerns grow, more people will look into getting software to protect their privacy, and it will reduce the accuracy of this method.

Comment: I agree with you, but the new H.25.3 SC version overcomes these limitations by using the new fallback ID feature:
"JavaScript H.25.3, released January 2013, contains a new fallback visitor identification method for visitors whose browser blocks the cookie set by Adobe’s data collection servers (called s_vi). Previously, if a cookie could not be set, visitors were identified using a combination of the IP address and user agent string during data collection."

This means that you don't have to have to identify the visitor by the user agent, ip etc. but you do it using a first party cookie.